# javax.resource.spi.work.ExecutionContext

Tags: java

any example on usage of javax.resource.spi.work.ExecutionContext ?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of example are you after? There are a few major open source projects you could look at for ideas.

For example, JBossWorkManager uses the ExecutionContext in its doWork() method, as does Spring's WorkManagerTaskExecutor in one of its doWork() methods.

You can find the sources in the respective source repositories, here are the links for [JBossWorkManager](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/resource/work/JBossWorkManager.java.html) and Spring [WorkManagerTaskExecutor](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.transaction/src/main/java/org/springframework/jca/work/WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java).